# Lock Screen Pattern Too Small After Android 4.3 Update on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean, pattern-lock

A few days ago, my Samsung Galaxy S3 finally got the OTA update to Android 4.3 from Verizon.

Before the update, when I was running Android 4.1.2, the pattern on my lock screen looked like the 1st image below. Not only was the pattern larger, but it also had a visible "shadow", providing an easy way to see how big each circle is before you begin highlighting.

After the update to Android 4.3, the pattern on my lock screen now looks like the 2nd image below. The pattern has decreased in size by about 30%, and it is now harder to see where each circle is before you begin highlighting (as I have started to do in the image below).

So my question is two-fold:

**1) Does there exist a way to make the lock screen pattern larger on Android 4.3 so that it looks more like it previously in Android 4.1.2 *without the use of a third-party app?*** I don't intend on using the space provided for widgets above the pattern, so a solution that causes this functionality to be removed in the process is acceptable.

**2) If no native solution exists, is there a third-party app that I can download that will allow me to substitute the default home lock screen pattern for one that is larger?** I am aware that there are app-specific lock screens with large patterns, but I am referring to the home lock screen only.

## Before Update (Android 4.1.2)

[image]

## After Update (Android 4.3):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> 1) **Does there exist a way to make the lock screen pattern larger on
>   Android 4.3 so that it looks more like it previously in Android 4.1.2
>   *without the use of a third-party app?***
>   I don't intend on using the
>   space provided for widgets above the pattern, so a solution that
>   causes this functionality to be removed in the process is acceptable.

As from above images it seems that the upper widget screen is comparatively similar in both images, I think the width of lock pattern is reduced.

So, I think you **can't** change the size of lock pattern *without the use of a third-party app*

> 2) **If no native solution exists, is there a third-party app that I can
>   download that will allow me to substitute the default home lock screen
>   pattern for one that is larger?** I am aware that there are app-specific
>   lock screens with large patterns, but I am referring to the home lock
>   screen only.

AFAIK, You can't replace the **home lock screen**.
You can ***disable the home lock screen* and *enable the third party app lock screen*, which will work as lock screen.**

Example: **[Go Locker!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock)**